# In the vsts extension How to get the value from a url parameter?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I created a vsts extension control with JavaScript and html and I added it to the WebLayout XML and everything works fine.

```
<FIELD name="Primary Products" refname="ECO.CI.CI.AppliesToProducts" type="PlainText" />
<Extensions>
     <Extension Id="v-jinzhe.csscontent-contentidea" />
</Extensions>
<ControlContribution Label="Primary Products:" Id="v-jinzhe.csscontent-contentidea.productpicker-control-contribution">
    <Inputs>
        <Input Id="FieldName" Value="ECO.CI.CI.AppliesToProducts" />
    </Inputs>
</ControlContribution>
```

But when I used [Copy template Url] I found that the value was not automatically set up like System.Tile.

**The Url like:**  https://th-jinzhe-vm01:8443/tfs/DefaultCollection/ContentTest/_workItems/create/Content%20Idea%20Request?%5BSystem.Title%5D=Intune%3A+&%5BECO.CI.CI.AppliesToProducts%5D=Microsoft+Intune(389d15a1-c6fa-bbb6-f3fd-523a62a2b3c5)

[image]

Does anyone know what needs to be set up in the WebLayout XML? Or there is a Client API to get the value from a url?

Comment: What's the detail version of your TFS2018? There isn't Copy template URL item for me. What's the result if you choose Capture? Is customer field included? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=vsts&tabs=browser